# reading UINT from Array of bytes

Tags: c++

I'm trying to read some values from a set of bytes

```
0D 01 00 02 43 AC 10 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 34 00 00 00
```

The structure of this is

```
struct
{
 char Action;
 char Type;
 UINT Serial;
 byte Length;
 char* message;
}
```

how can i read it?

I tried to read it like this:

```
int index = 2; // skip the first 2 bytes
byte Type = data[index];
UINT Serial = (UINT)((data[index++] << 24) + (data[index++] << 16)
    + (data[index++] << 8) + data[index++]);

byte Length = data[index++];
std::string Message(reinterpret_cast<char*>(data) + index, Length);
```

this is working as i'm getting the correct message, `"              4             "`  but the Serial is 0, it should not be zero.

whats wrong here, Looking for an eaiser way to read data. (packets)

Comment: `UINT Serial = (UINT)((data[index++] << 24) + (data[index++] << 16)
    + (data[index++] << 8) + data[index++]);` may cause undefined behavior. Try using `UINT Serial = (UINT)((data[2] << 24) + (data[3] << 16)
    + (data[4] << 8) + data[5]);` if the data is in big endian.

Comment: `UINT` smells like Windows, in which case the data is little endian, and you should reverse the index for the bytes.

Comment: @Dean says that the data are packets. So I thought that the data may be in network byteorder (= big endian).

Comment: ty Mike, Working now

Comment: Can't you define that struct and then cast the pointer to data to that struct like this: struct myStruct *s = (myStruct *)&data; then you can use s->Serial;